# Wrapper Class in a Map

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, wrapper-class, repeat

I have a wrapper class inside of a map that I want to display on a VFP. The output value of the map is:

```
{2017-07-13 16:28:02=CaseInfo:[caseNumber=00033490, taskData=Task:{WhatId=500S0000008l5A3IAI, Id=00TS000000Ul9poMAB, CreatedDate=2017-07-13 16:28:02, Comments__c=Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type SENT, OwnerId=00534000009QnEtAAK, Subject=Email: Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type SENT, AccountId=001S000000raQdyIAE, CreatedById=00534000009QnEtAAK, RecordTypeId=01280000000BawwAAC}], 
2017-07-13 16:28:30=CaseInfo:[caseNumber=00033490, taskData=Task:{WhatId=500S0000008l5A3IAI, Id=00TS000000Ul9puMAB, CreatedDate=2017-07-13 16:28:30, Comments__c=RESPONSE, OwnerId=00580000003HZZnAAO, Subject=RE: Sandbox: Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type RESPONSE, CreatedById=00580000003HZZnAAO, RecordTypeId=01280000000BawwAAC}], 
2017-07-17 18:57:22=CaseInfo:[caseNumber=00033494, taskData=Task:{WhatId=500S0000008lPkSIAU, Id=00TS000000UlRjlMAF, CreatedDate=2017-07-17 18:57:22, Comments__c=TEST COMMENTS From: Olivia Porter, OwnerId=00534000009ceS2AAI, Subject=RE: Sandbox: Wire In -, CreatedById=00534000009ceS2AAI}]}`
```

I want to pull out the key, the caseNumber, and the Task Subject. I am able to pull out the key and the caseNumber but unable to delve further into the map. How would I go about doing something like this?

```
<apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap}" var="taskTime">
    <th colspan="5" id="casenumber">{!taskTime}</th> <!--displays the key-->
    <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap[taskTime]}" var="caseInfo"> <!--displays the whole CaseInfo value-->
        <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap[taskTime[caseInfo]]}" var="taskData"><!--does not work-->
            <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap[taskTime[caseInfo[taskData]]]}" var="task"><!--does not work-->
                <tr>
                    <td>{!taskData.CaseNumber}</td>
                    <td>{!task.Subject}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

For ease of viewing, I hope the returned value is enough to understand the question. If not, I can add the wrapper class and map in.

UPDATE:
Wrapper

```
class CaseInfo {
    public String caseNumber {get;set;}
    public Task taskData {get;set;}

    CaseInfo(String caseNumber, Task taskData) {
        this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
        this.taskData = taskData;
    }
}

public viewAllCaseCommentsActivitiesController() {
    ....
    orderedTaskList1 = [SELECT (SELECT CreatedDate, Comments__c, OwnerId, Subject, Owner.Name, AccountId, WhatId, CreatedById, Account.Name FROM Tasks WHERE Private__c = FALSE AND (Status = 'Completed' OR Status = 'Closed')
                            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC), AccountId, CaseNumber, Merchant_Number__c FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId AND Id IN :accountIds];
    caseTaskMap = new Map<String, CaseInfo>();
        for(Case c : orderedTaskList1){
            for (Task t : c.Tasks) {
                caseTaskMap.put(''+t.CreatedDate, new CaseInfo(c.CaseNumber,t));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You should include the actual wrapper definition.

Comment: @AdrianLarson added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use in the repeat

```
caseInfo.CaseNumber
```

Since caseInfo is akin to the loop variable in a for loop and each instance would be a wrapper record

When using the repeats think of each one as a for loop. Maps are accessed using [keys] and values are accessed using dot notation. The var is the loop variable

Working example:

**Controller**

```
public class myControllerExample{


    public Map<String,caseInfo> caseTaskMap {get;set;}

    public myControllerExample(){
        caseTaskMap = New Map<String,caseInfo>{
            string.valueOf(system.now().addDays(-3)) => New caseInfo('12345'),
            string.valueOf(system.now().addDays(-2)) => New caseInfo('123456'),
            string.valueOf(system.now().addDays(-1)) => New caseInfo('123457')
        };
    }

    public class caseInfo{

        public Task taskData {get;set;}
        public String caseNumber {get;set;}

        public caseInfo(String caseNumber){
            this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
            taskData = New task(Subject = 'Test Subject for: ' + caseNumber);
        }

    }



}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="myControllerExample">

<div>
    <table>
        <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap}" var="taskTimeKeys">
                <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap[taskTimeKeys]}" var="caseInfoRows"><!--does not work-->
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!caseInfoRows.CaseNumber}</td>
                            <td>{!caseInfoRows.taskData.Subject}</td>
                        </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Map values:

```
{
 2017-07-22 13:39:12=caseInfo:[caseNumber=12345, 
     taskData=Task:{Subject=Test Subject for: 12345}], 
 2017-07-23 13:39:12=caseInfo:[caseNumber=123456, 
     taskData=Task:{Subject=Test Subject for: 123456}], 
 2017-07-24 13:39:12=caseInfo:[caseNumber=123457, 
     taskData=Task:{Subject=Test Subject for: 123457}]
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, unfortunately I get an error message `Unknown property 'viewAllCaseCommentsActivitiesController.CaseInfo.CaseNumber'
Error is in expression '{!caseInfo.CaseNumber}' in component <apex:repeat> in page viewallcasecommentsactivities`. This made me think that perhaps it wasn't possible to move down more layers or that the 'CaseInfo' wasn't being read as a key

Comment: @Olivia - Ok. give me a few minutes and I will get you a working example

Comment: @Olivia Did you expose that variable as a property? You need to define a getter/setter e.g. `public String CaseNumber { get; private set; }`

Comment: @AdrianLarson I did add it and I still get no response.

Comment: @Olivia - Updated with example and removed the unnecessary repeats

Comment: @Eric thank you the wrapper class works and I was able to use a Comparable to sort the list in the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to

```
<tr>
<td>{!caseInfoRows.CaseNumber}</td>
<td>{!caseInfoRows.taskData.Subject}</td>
</tr>
```

that uses standard Visualforce components is

```
<apex:outputText value="{!caseInfoRows.CaseNumber} /> -- <nbsp/>
<apex:outputText value="{!caseInfoRows.taskData.Subject} /><br/>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps **[edit]** your post to clarify *why* this change would be an improvement?